Higher-order Stirling approximation
I'm trying to obtain higher-order terms of the Stirling series by iteratively substituting $\Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s)$. Here is the procedure:
\begin{eqnarray}
\Gamma(s+1)&=&e^{s\ln s-s}\sqrt{2\pi s}\left(1+\frac{A}{s}+O\left(\frac{1}{s^2}\right)\right)\\
&=&s\Gamma(s)\\
&=&se^{(s-1)\left(\ln (s-1)-1\right)}\sqrt{2\pi(s-1)}\left(1+\frac{A}{s-1}+O\left(\frac{1}{s^2}\right)\right)\\
&=&se^{(s-1)\left(\ln s-\frac{1}{s}-1+O\left(\frac{1}{s^2}\right)\right)}\sqrt{2\pi s}\left(1-\frac{1}{s}\right)^{1/2}\left(1+\frac{A}{s}\left(1-\frac{1}{s}\right)^{-1}+O\left(\frac{1}{s^2}\right)\right)\\
&=&e^{s\ln s-s+\frac{1}{s}+O\left(\frac{1}{s^2}\right)}\sqrt{2\pi s}\left(1-\frac{1}{2s}+O\left(\frac{1}{s^2}\right)\right)\left(1+\frac{A}{s}+O\left(\frac{1}{s^2}\right)\right)\\
&=&e^{s\ln s-s}\sqrt{2\pi s}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{s}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2s}\right)\left(1+\frac{A}{s}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{s^2}\right)\right]\\
&=&e^{s\ln s-s}\sqrt{2\pi s}\left[1+\left(A+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{1}{s}+O\left(\frac{1}{s^2}\right)\right]
\end{eqnarray}
Once I identify the coefficient of the $\frac{1}{s}$ term, I get $A=A+\frac{1}{2}$, which is completely nonsense! What's wrong with this procedure?

There's a nice family of factorial approximations at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2012.11.023 which you may find interesting.

@PM2Ring Seems interesting. Thanks a lot!

The mistake is to do with the fact that if $f \sim g + O(\frac{1}{s^2})$, then $s f \sim s g + O(\frac{1}{s})$, so the error term is different.
In the exponent, you therefore have to expand $\ln(s-1)-1$ to quadratic instead of linear order, which leads to a different value:
\begin{align}
s \exp\Big[ (s-1)(\ln(s-1)-1)\Big] &= \exp\Big[\ln(s)+ (s-1)(\ln(s-1)-1)\Big] \\
&= \exp\Big[ s\ln s - s + \frac{1}{2s} + O(\frac{1}{s^2})\Big]
\end{align}
Note that the factor of two here is missing from your calculation, and resolves things:
\begin{equation}
\Big(1+\frac{1}{2s}\Big)\Big(1-\frac{1}{2s}\Big)\Big(1+\frac{A}{s}\Big) = 1+\frac{A}{s} + O(\frac{1}{s^2})
\end{equation}
This fixes the "A discrepancy", but, to be honest, I am not sure how you expect this procedure to give you higher order terms.

Oh, then the recursion formula is useless for estimating higher-order corrections... Thanks!
